# CakePHP paginate results with a condition on another table linked with HABTM

Tags: php, cakephp, has-and-belongs-to-many, conditional-statements, pagination

I've done some searching but I can't find anything relevant enough/working for my scenario. I've got:

```
Jobs <--> HABTM (Users_jobs table) <--> Users
```

I would like to do a `paginate()` from my `Job` controller with a condition on the `User.id`, as I do need to fetch -and paginate- all the jobs from the current user.

If you do provide a link to another topic/site, please provide an explanation with it and how you would apply it to my case.

Cheers,
Nicolas.

Comment: Can you describe the condition you would like to do and also describe what fields the result set should contain?

Comment: Exactly what I've done on my question: a condition on the `User.id` field and the result is the `Job` array. Cheers.

Comment: No one has any suggestion for my issue?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your HABTM associations are setup correctly (`cake bake` would expect a join table of `jobs_users` rather than `users_jobs` (see: [Cakephp-HABTM](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1044/hasAndBelongsToMany-HABTM))  If they are, change the references to JobsUser in the example below to UsersJob to match the layout you described.

```
//In an action in jobs_controller.php

//Fake a HasOne association to the JobsUser model, setting $reset to false
$this->Job->bindModel(array(
    'hasOne' => array(
        'JobsUser'
    )
), false);

//Setup the paginate conditions, grouping on job.id
//Set $user_id to the user to filter results by (can also be an array of users)
$options = array(
    'group' => 'Job.id',
    'conditions' => array(
        'JobsUser.user.id' => $user_id
    )
);
$this->paginate = $options;
$users = $this->paginate();
```